# JavaScript autopopulate working days for a set interval of days

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need some help with javascript. I have this javascript functions that populate dates of different interval when user enter a start date. Now the user need to populate only working dates (no weekends and holidays). How can I make sure that when incrementing days it should only be a workday?

My code:

```
function GetModifiedDate(date, noOfDaysAdded) {
        var inputstring = date;
        var dString = inputstring.split('/');
        var dt = new Date(dString[2], dString[0] - 1, dString[1]);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + parseInt(noOfDaysAdded));
        var finaldate = (String(dt.getMonth() + 1)) + '/' + (String(dt.getDate())) + '/' + (String(dt.getFullYear()));
        return finaldate;
    }
function AutoPopulateDatesForLndMgmtCust(obj) {
                var val = obj.value;
                var table = $('#tblLndMgmtCust');
                var rowLength = table[0].rows.length;
                var modifieddate = val;

                     incrementDay = [2, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2, 10, 4, 10, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1];

                for (var i = 0; i < rowLength - 2; i += 1) {
                    var row = table[0].rows[i + 2];
                    var cell = row.cells[2];

                    modifieddate = GetModifiedDate(modifieddate, incrementDay[i] * 1);
                    cell.children[0].children[0].value = modifieddate;
                }
            }
```

Thanks much!

Comment: How do you want to know, if a date is a holiday in a certain region? Holidays can be any day of the week. So without a backing data-store, that will check a date against the user input, this will be a pretty hard job.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date(2018, 03, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0);

var day = d.getDay();
var isWeekend = (day == 6) || (day == 0);    // 6 = Saturday, 0 = Sunday

var day = d.getDay();
var isWorkday = (day != 6) && (day != 0);
```